# Express app not accessible sometimes only for some users

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, express, amazon-ec2

The app is not accessible sometimes but only for some users. In the same LAN also, some users can access but some cannot.

The web app was designed with following technologies

- Node
- Angular
- Express
- MySql.

It's hosted in `AWS EC2`, `MySql` is also installed on the same `EC2 instance`.

I have no idea how this is happening. The server was running all the time.
[image: Error when not accessible]

Comment: how are you handling your node server ??? to stay permanently running?

Comment: Check if all of your users' possible IPs match with the inbound of the security group you are using in the AWS EC2.

Comment: @JaiDixit I am using forever.

Comment: @holydragon Inbound source for HTTP and HTTPS are set to ANYWHERE (0.0.0.0/0, ::/0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This eror is not related your application - it's just that domain can not be resolved. You should check your DNS setting on server and on clients. See also instruction [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217912538-How-to-fix-err-name-not-resolved-), for example.

Comment: The issue was that the client has added new NS without removing the old NS.